# Statistical analysis of change in Variable 'Y' over time within a session for a group

Tags: regression, time-series, statistical-significance, anova, repeated-measures

I want to see if there is an increase in my dependent variable 'Y' within a session for a group A (10 participants).

**My research question:**
IS there a significant increase in 'Y' within-session for group A?

For every second, dependent variable 'Y' and sensor noise 'X' were sampled. 'Y' will be eliminated if the 'X' = YES. The session time varies for each participant (between 20 to 50 seconds). There are 10 participants. Every participant have around 20 sessions.

My data looks like this for every session:

[image: Sample Data]

**Q1: What statistical method should I use to show if the variable 'Y' significantly increased or decreased or no pattern observed within session for the group?** I am aware of basic methods such as ANOVA.

Q2: I was thinking about the following method:
**(1) treat each second as repeated measures and perform ANOVA with time as IV, and Y as DV for all 10 participants? In this case, the varying session time becomes a problem. How to handle this?**

Q3: **is there any time-series statistical method that I can use to analyse the change in 'Y' within a session for the sessions numbers 1, 10 and 20 (individually) for all 10 participants.**

Thank you

Comment: What is *Y*? What's the comparison? I.e., are the groups being subjected to differing interventions of some kind? Is there any with-in group collaboration among participants? Is there any "learning" taking place within a session or over time? And so on...